# Wordpress Homepage blank but other working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have this .htaccess file inside my wordpress folder.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 / http://afh.asso.fr/presentation
```

I wanted to redirect http://afh.asso.fr to http://afh.asso.fr/presentation

How is that possible with my current .htaccess file ?

Thank you so much for any help, I really appreciate it :)

Explained otherwise:
I have this website that works fine :
https://afh.asso.fr/avec-lafh/qui-sommes-nous/histoire-de-lafh-en-video/

Every page is ok.

But http://www.afh.asso.fr is not ok (the home page).

How could I redirect this afh.asso.fr to another page, specifying the url myself in a .htaccess file for example ?

I already have .htaccess file for wordpress.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
Redirect 301 / /avec-lafh/qui-sommes-nous/presentation/
```

EDIT:
It looks like your using WordPress too, can you not change your homepage to a visible page, to do this:

- Go to settings
- Click Reading
- Select page you'd like to be the homepage.

Comment: Thank you, a page was already selected and it does not load this page... I really do not understand now...

Comment: Which page is selected? Does it use a set template? You could try using front-page.php, this will be your homepage by default.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer Jonny :) Whatever page I chose, it does not work. I tried with many, that are working otherwise on the website. What is front-page.php ? How can I set this up ?

Comment: If you name a php file front-page.php and add some dummy text, see if it pulls into your homepage?

Comment: Where do I need to name that php file and put it ? Via FTP ?

Comment: And I did not tell but I guess you guessed it the redirection does not work :(

Comment: How is your site currently set up? Do you normally FTP? If so, FTP a page named front-page.php in the same location you have header.php and footer.php with some text in, this should then become your homepage

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I am currently using wordpress and I did not use FTP for this :(

Comment: How are you managing your files? Wherever you would go to change your files, you need to try and add the file I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a redirect rule before default WP front controller rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ presentation [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Regex `^/?$` will match landing page and redirect to `/presentation` with `301` status code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This redirection does not work, I still have the same blank page on Home and everything else working :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately…

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not get any redirection, how is that even possible... I have two requests, one for favicon and one for afh.asso.fr.

Comment: That means this htacceas is not being used. WP might be using some proxy plug-in